# When using a formula in a custom field how can I tell if I'm in a sandbox or production?

Tags: formula, custom-field

I have a custom field that I store a url in. If we are in a sandbox I need it to point to an external QA server. If we are in production I want it to point to our production server.

I'm looking through the fields I have available to merge and I'm just not seeing anything that seems to be able to tell me if I'm in a sandbox. Nor can I find documentation on what variables I have to check. I was using

```
IF ($Organization.Id=='[hardcoded full sandbox org ID]' 
    || 
    $Organization.Id=='[hard coded dev sandbox ord id]',
   '[our QA server]',
   '[our live server]'
)
```

This worked until we did a full refresh and the ord IDs changed. I would like something that can survive a full refresh. Can anyone help or point me to the best documentation to help me solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: While it's generally a bad idea to hardcode in IDs, presumably your production instance isn't going to have it's ID changed. Could you not reverse the logic of this so that the QA server is the else condition? `IF($Organization.Id='[Production]','[live server]','[QA Server]')`

Comment: @ToddSprinkel: Possible yes, but the fail-safe mode for when this code goes to production is to keep the live server in the else mode. I would rather have to keep changing my org IDs in the formula than possibly cause the URL to be wrong in production.

Comment: why not use hierarchical custom settings at org level - you can define the URL and you can change it as a data change rather than changing the formula as @Himanshu suggests. Hierarchical custom settings can be used in formula fields, List custom settings can not

Comment: @crop1645 - I'm still really new to SF, this seems like a good idea, I'll see if I can run it by the powers that be. Where would I make such a setting?

Comment: `Setup | Develop | Custom Settings`

Comment: I'd be interested to learn if production org ids can ever change and if so, under what circumstances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you haven't defined the my domain for your org. you can update your formula in following way

```
if(CONTAINS($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, 'cs41') || 
CONTAINS($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, 'cs32'),
'EXTERNAL SERVER SANDBOX URL,'EXTERNAL SERVER PROD URL')
```

Comment: the CS## changed when we do full refreshes as well. BUT maybe I can just figure out how to check for the cs at the beginning of the server name.

Comment: correct. that is the only way.

Comment: so many partner server and enterprise server url options. What do they all mean?

Comment: every api url is available with api version and I guess you know about Salesforce API version which update 3 times a year.

Comment: I went a little more specific with my code to prevent possible false positives: `"http://" & IF (OR( FIND("://cs",LEFT($Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_350, FIND(".com",$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_350))) > 0, FIND("://skuid.cs",LEFT($Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_350, FIND(".com",$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_350))) > 0), '[Test Server name]', '[live server name]') & "[path to file]"`